# How to launch and work on external application GUI using python

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, ui-automation

I am launching external app using python module (os.startfile(path of app)).
After launch , I want to selection option for that UI.
How can I do using python.

Comment: Please have a look at ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: There are several GUI automation tools on different OSes. Need more details to recommend you a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a nice **[project called pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/)**. I'd recommend looking into that.

I think that the project is mostly about testing, but perhaps it will do for simple gui control in-code